# Redefine URL of pagebrowser of tt_news in TYPO3

Tags: navigation, uri, typo3, tt-news

In my page structure in a TYPO3 project I have a root page and a "home" page. I configured the root page to show the content of "home". In "home" I have the tt_news frontend plugin LIST with a pagebrowser.

When the user is on `/` (root page), the pagebrowser-link is like

- `/4eb0456e49c1a9134638cf8d76b50406/?tx_ttnews%5Bpointer%5D=1`

but when the user is on `/home/` the pagebrowser-link is

- `/home/4eb0456e49c1a9134638cf8d76b50406/?tx_ttnews%5Bpointer%5D=1`

I need the link on both pages to be with the `/home/`. Is this possible?

I'm using `CoolURI`, if that matters...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set rootpage `/` as a shortcut to `home` (or reverse) instead duplicating the content, That way links should always point to the `/home` even if accessed via `/`

In very general displaying the same content on many sites is wrong concept and can result with lowering ranks in search engines.

Comment: thanks, I remember I already had that solution before, but this leads me to another problem: I work with backbone.js Routers. This JS-Framework allows me to work with the history-pushstate (kind of "live" URL rewriting). No problem with new browsers, but on old browsers which don't implement the pushstate-library, it falls back to "/#home/..." (hash URL). As a result there is a infinite loop: Typo3 redirects to "/home/..." and backbone.js Router redirects to "/#home/...".
Do you have any ideas how to solve that? Thank you!